# Link field to content

Tags: 7, views, navigation

In my view I have 4 fields including an image. I want to link a field other than image field to the content but there is no such option as for the image field i.e "Link to". How can I get this option?Or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rewrite the output of that field and make it a link. Rewrite works for all fields - some fields do offer a link output in their settings though and might be the better option if available.

Steps to take:

1. add a path to the content and exclude it from output.

[image]

2. rewrite the output of the field you want to add a link to.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) At your field, click on the link you which to add link.
2) Link image to: choose nothing
3) Look for REWRITE RESULTS and click on it
4) Check Output this field as a link
5) Insert your link path

Comment: Thanku @peifa, but this is not the right way. The answer below by Andre-B is correct. :)

Comment: Sorry...next time i show the picture too. Lol. Btw, does anyone has any knowledge on Ubercart Webform Integration module?

Comment: pfeifa, your solution only works if that field has the option to be displayed as a link, that is not available for all fields. my solution is generic and works for all fields (unless the markup of that field breaks the html anchor element)

Comment: Oh thank for advice. Andre-B. Btw do you know how to change or add field in ubercart (customer information)